# Semantic-UI Image properties not working with semantic-ui-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I´m trying to use the official [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction) for the first time with React. I´ve built a brand new react application:

```
$ create-react-app test
```

And I then tried to add the same react image as follows in **App.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

        <div className="ui container">
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          <Image src={logo} avatar/>
          <Image src={logo} size='mini'/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The result shows me 2 big react `{logo}` images, not mini or avatar styled:

[image]

Ideas of what I´m missing here ?

Comment: I have tried to re-implement your example code but I'm getting the same render as you.  I'm as stuck as you are, but looking into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantic UI React requires a Semantic UI' CSS, you forgot to setup it, [here](http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#css) is instuctions. We will also add an example setup with CRA soon.

Answer (score 0):

You might have found your answer already, but not seeing it here, so adding solution for the same error I got while using Image component with svg icon

```
import { Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';

<div className="ui container">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <Image as={Logo} title="logo" avatar />
</div>
```

Hope this helps some one!