# Semantic-ui-react library does not work; no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

`semantic-ui-react` does not work on my browser and I'm not sure why - there aren't any errors or problems in the console.

This is the component from the library `semantic-ui`; it's from this file `UptimeGuarantee.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Header, Icon , Image} from 'semantic-ui-react'

const HeaderExampleUsersIcon = () => (
  <div>
    <Header as='h2' icon textAlign='center'>
      <Icon name='users' circular />
      <Header.Content>
        Friends
      </Header.Content>
    </Header>
    <Image centered size='large' src='/assets/images/wireframe/centered-paragraph.png' />
  </div>
)

export default HeaderExampleUsersIcon
```

and on my App.js I call this component:

```
import React, { Component , PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import HeaderExampleUsersIcon from './UptimeGuarantee'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
                </div>
                <p className="App-intro">To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.</p>
                <Button primary>Primary</Button>
                <HeaderExampleUsersIcon />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609711/semantic-ui-image-properties-not-working-with-semantic-ui-react/

Answer (score 34):

semantic-ui-react is only components without styles and fonts.

You should import styles from semantic-ui-css

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

or add styles to html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.css"></link>
```

Comment: Where do you ```import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';``` ?  I've tried to do it in the .jsx file and also the application.js file ( using webpacker to use React on Rails )

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. use 'npm install semantic-ui-css' to resolve module not found errors

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that you

```
npm install --save semantic-ui-react
```

AND

```
npm install --save semantic-ui-css
```

in your terminal (in the directory of the project)

The second dependancy will allow you to apply styles. Just put

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

as well in the components you are working on.